# Inheriting IObjectSafetyImpl for safe javascript activex control in C++

Tags: javascript, visual-c++, activex

Im having trouble setting my control to be safe.
I found this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/b7488e74-bb25-4561-b852-e4ed06239c31) which explains how it needs to be done.
I did as explained:

```
class myctrl: public COleControl, public IObjectSafetyImpl<myctrl,INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER | INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA>
{
```

then, i added the following:

```
BEGIN_COM_MAP(myctrl)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IObjectSafety)
END_COM_MAP()
```

The "BEGIN_COM_MAP" causes me trouble and i dont know why.
it says "Lock" & "Unlock" are not members of myctrl.
I couldnt find anything related to it and what I need to do with these two members
I also get the error:

```
Error   3   error C2660: 'CCmdTarget::InternalQueryInterface' : function does not take 4 arguments
```

Comment: You're mixing MFC COM and ATL COM - I'm not sure you'll get very far like that. Have a look at [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751977(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Comment: @RogerRowland this control was once registered trough DllRegisterServer and it worked fine (the first method explained in the link). Now I want to take it out of the registry and do it inside the control by IObjectSafety. But Im not sure how. What am I mixing exactly?

Comment: There are two main ways to do COM in VC++ - one is to use the Active Template Library (ATL), the other is to use MFC via `COleControl`. You went the MFC route, but the link you used was only for ATL COM objects - totally different code. I've added some MFC code in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MFC COM, you need to add some boilerplate code to your `COleControl` derived class. Warning - some big copy/paste coming up so please excuse typos!

First, in your control's header file, add the following

```
DECLARE_INTERFACE_MAP()
BEGIN_INTERFACE_PART(ObjectSafety, IObjectSafety)
    STDMETHOD(GetInterfaceSafetyOptions)(REFIID riid, DWORD __RPC_FAR *pdwSupportedOptions, DWORD __RPC_FAR *pdwEnabledOptions);
    STDMETHOD(SetInterfaceSafetyOptions)(REFIID riid, DWORD dwOptionSetMask, DWORD dwEnabledOptions);
END_INTERFACE_PART(ObjectSafety)
```

Then, in the implementation file, add this

```
BEGIN_INTERFACE_MAP(myctrl, COleControl)
    INTERFACE_PART(myctrl, IID_IObjectSafety, ObjectSafety)
END_INTERFACE_MAP()

// Implementation of IObjectSafety
STDMETHODIMP myctrl::XObjectSafety::GetInterfaceSafetyOptions(
    REFIID riid,
    DWORD __RPC_FAR *pdwSupportedOptions,
    DWORD __RPC_FAR *pdwEnabledOptions)
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE_EX(myctrl, ObjectSafety)

        if (!pdwSupportedOptions || !pdwEnabledOptions)
        {
            return E_POINTER;
        }

        *pdwSupportedOptions = INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER | INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA;
        *pdwEnabledOptions = 0;

        if (NULL == pThis->GetInterface(&riid))
        {
            TRACE("Requested interface is not supported./n");
            return E_NOINTERFACE;
        }

        // What interface is being checked out anyhow?
        OLECHAR szGUID[39];
        int i = StringFromGUID2(riid, szGUID, 39);

        if (riid == IID_IDispatch)
        {
            // Client wants to know if object is safe for scripting
            *pdwEnabledOptions = INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER;
            return S_OK;
        }
        else if (riid == IID_IPersistPropertyBag
            || riid == IID_IPersistStreamInit
            || riid == IID_IPersistStorage
            || riid == IID_IPersistMemory)
        {
            // Those are the persistence interfaces COleControl derived controls support
            // as indicated in AFXCTL.H
            // Client wants to know if object is safe for initializing from persistent data
            *pdwEnabledOptions = INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA;
            return S_OK;
        }
        else
        {
            // Find out what interface this is, and decide what options to enable
            TRACE("We didn't account for the safety of this interface, and it's one we support.../n");
            return E_NOINTERFACE;
        } 
}
STDMETHODIMP myctrl::XObjectSafety::SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(
    REFIID riid,
    DWORD dwOptionSetMask,
    DWORD dwEnabledOptions)
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE_EX(myctrl, ObjectSafety)

        OLECHAR szGUID[39];
    // What is this interface anyway?
    // We can do a quick lookup in the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Interface
    int i = StringFromGUID2(riid, szGUID, 39);

    if (0 == dwOptionSetMask && 0 == dwEnabledOptions)
    {
        // the control certainly supports NO requests through the specified interface
        // so it's safe to return S_OK even if the interface isn't supported.
        return S_OK;
    }

    // Do we support the specified interface?
    if (NULL == pThis->GetInterface(&riid))
    {
        TRACE1("%s is not support./n", szGUID);
        return E_FAIL;
    }


    if (riid == IID_IDispatch)
    {
        TRACE("Client asking if it's safe to call through IDispatch./n");
        TRACE("In other words, is the control safe for scripting?/n");
        if (INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER == dwOptionSetMask && INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER == dwEnabledOptions)
        {
            return S_OK;
        }
        else
        {
            return E_FAIL;
        }
    }
    else if (riid == IID_IPersistPropertyBag
        || riid == IID_IPersistStreamInit
        || riid == IID_IPersistStorage
        || riid == IID_IPersistMemory)
    {
        TRACE("Client asking if it's safe to call through IPersist*./n");
        TRACE("In other words, is the control safe for initializing from persistent data?/n");

        if (INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA == dwOptionSetMask && INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA == dwEnabledOptions)
        {
            return NOERROR;
        }
        else
        {
            return E_FAIL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TRACE1("We didn't account for the safety of %s, and it's one we support.../n", szGUID);
        return E_FAIL;
    }
}
STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) myctrl::XObjectSafety::AddRef()
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE_EX_(myctrl, ObjectSafety)
        return (ULONG)pThis->ExternalAddRef();
}
STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) myctrl::XObjectSafety::Release()
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE_EX_(myctrl, ObjectSafety)
        return (ULONG)pThis->ExternalRelease();
}
STDMETHODIMP myctrl::XObjectSafety::QueryInterface(
    REFIID iid, LPVOID* ppvObj)
{
    METHOD_PROLOGUE_EX_(myctrl, ObjectSafety)
        return (HRESULT)pThis->ExternalQueryInterface(&iid, ppvObj);
}
```

Comment: thank you. its definitely a progress. however once I inherit like: `class myctrl: public COleControl, public IObjectSafety`, I have errors raising from `DECLARE_DYNCREATE(myctrl)` and from `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(myctrl)`: `Error 1 error C2259: 'myctrl' : cannot instantiate abstract class` So I changed to to `DYNAMIC`, which solved the errors, but it seems my control isnt working at all now

Comment: I have no words to describe how much you helped me. I got confused between ATL & MFC. Where is all this code taken from? I want to understand a bit more. The issue is maybe fixed but to be honest, Its not a work i started and the field is mostly unknown to me.

Comment: Most of it looks to be taken from Microsoft's "SafeCtl.exe implements IObjectSafety in ActiveX control" example - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164119